# fill a linked list, having information about the length encoded in the type, with values

Tags: haskell

I'm currently having some fun approaching typelevel programming.
Consider the following version of a linked list

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

module ExpLinkedList where

import           GHC.TypeLits (Nat, KnownNat , type (-), type (+))
import           Data.Proxy   (Proxy(..))
import           Data.Kind    (Type)
import           Fcf          (TyEq, If, Eval)

data LinkedList (n :: Nat) (a :: Type) where
  Nil  :: LinkedList 0 a
  (:@) :: a -> LinkedList n a -> LinkedList (n + 1) a

infixr 5 :@

someList :: LinkedList 2 String
someList = "test" :@ "list" :@ Nil
```

## I was wondering whether it's possible to define a function which `extend`s a `LinkedList`?

For example

```hs
extend :: forall m n a . LinkedList n a -> a -> LinkedList (n + m) a
extend vec elem = undefined

example :: LinkedList 5 String
example = extend @3 ("foo" :@ "bar" :@ Nil) "hi"
-- could be: "hi" :@ "hi" :@ "hi" :@ "foo" :@ "bar" :@ Nil
```

I came up with different approaches which all got stuck sooner or later... Here are two of them:

### Recursive Approach

In this approach, the end condition is encoded by an overlapping typeclass instance

```hs
class Extend (b :: Nat) where
  ex :: a -> LinkedList n a -> LinkedList (n + b) a

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Extend 0  where
  ex _ vec = vec

instance Extend n where
  ex a vec = nextEx newVec
  --                ^
  --  • Couldn't match type ‘(n1 + 1) + (n - 1)’ with ‘n1 + n’
  --    Expected type: LinkedList (n1 + n) a
  --      Actual type: LinkedList ((n1 + 1) + (n - 1)) a
    where
      newVec = a :@ vec
      nextEx = ex @(n - 1) a
```

### Inductive Approach

```hs
type NextElement (n :: Nat) = Just (n - 1)

class BuildHelper (v :: Maybe Nat) (a :: Type) where
  type CNE v a :: Type
  buildNext :: Proxy v -> a -> CNE v a

instance BuildHelper 'Nothing a where
  type CNE 'Nothing a = LinkedList 0 a
  buildNext _ a = Nil

instance BuildHelper ('Just m) a where
  type CNE ('Just m) a = LinkedList (m + 1) a
  buildNext _ a = a :@ buildNext proxy a
--                     ^
-- • Couldn't match expected type ‘LinkedList m a’
--                  with actual type ‘CNE
--                                      (If (TyEq m 0) 'Nothing ('Just (m - 1))) 
    where
      proxy = Proxy @(NextElement m)
```

Evaluating this with pen and paper seems to work

```
-- buildNext (Proxy @(Just 2) True) :: proxy -> Bool -> Vector 3 Bool
-- = a :@ buildNext @(NextElement 2) a
-- = a :@ buildNext @(Just 1) a
-- = a :@ a :@ buildNext @(NextElement 1) a
-- = a :@ a :@ buildNext @(Just 0) a
-- = a :@ a :@ a :@ buildNext @(NextElement 0) a
-- = a :@ a :@ a :@ buildNext @(Nothing) a
-- = a :@ a :@ a :@ Nil
```

Basically GHC is not able to proof that `m` matches `(m - 1) + 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical use case for singletons.

Moreover, this solution relies on arithmetic properties, which are not available natively in GHC's typechecker, but are provided by the [ghc-typelits-natnormalise](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-typelits-natnormalise) plugin.

#### Plugin for reasoning about Nat

Specifically, appending length-indexed lists makes use of the associativity of `(+)`: in the case where `m = p + 1`, the type of output lists in the signature of `extend` is `LList (n + m) = LList (n + (p + 1))` which requires associativity to equal `LList ((n + p) + 1)` so that the constructor `(:@)` can be used. We also need commutativity unless we're careful in our code and proofs to not mix up `1 + p` and `p + 1` for example. In any case, installing that package and adding the following line teaches GHC some basic arithmetic:

```hs
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin GHC.TypeLits.Normalise #-}  -- from the package ghc-typelits-natnormalise
```

Note that we won't have to do any such reasoning explicitly in code; the plugin provides knowledge to the compiler during typechecking.

#### Singletons

The function `extend :: forall n m a. a -> LList m a -> LList (n + m) a` needs to look at the value of `m` to know how many `a`s to insert; we must change the type of `extend` to provide the necessary run-time information. A general solution is offered by singletons. Specifically we can define the following *singleton type* for the `Nat` kind, which has the characteristic that the run time representation of a value of type `SNat n` (i.e., look only at the constructors `SZ` and `SS`) uniquely determines the index `n`:

```hs
data SNat (n :: Nat) where
  SZ :: SNat 0
  SS :: SNat n -> SNat (1 + n)
```

- See also the blog post [Introduction to singletons](https://blog.jle.im/entry/introduction-to-singletons-1.html).

#### Definition of `extend`

Then the idea is to change the signature from `extend :: forall n. ...` to `extend :: SNat n -> ...`, augmenting quantification on `Nat` (`forall n`), which will be erased at run time, with a `SNat n` parameter with a concrete run-time representation. The function can then be defined by pattern-matching on the `SNat n` argument:

```hs
extend :: SNat n -> a -> LList m a -> LList (n + m) a
extend SZ _ ys = ys
extend (SS n) x ys = x :@ extend n x ys
```

Remark that if we ignore the types, this definition is identical to a variant of `extend` on simple lists (not indexed by their length) using simple Peano naturals. The function `extend` is one of many examples with indexed types which are merely more precisely typed versions of unindexed programs:

```hs
-- Peano representation of natural numbers
data PNat where
  Z :: PNat
  S :: PNat -> PNat

-- Non-indexed variant of extend
extendP :: PNat -> a -> [a] -> [a]
extendP Z _ ys = ys
extendP (S n) x ys = x : extendP n x ys
```

#### Example

An example using `extend`:

```
example :: LList 5 String
example = extend (SS (SS (SS SZ))) "hi" ("foo" :@ "bar" :@ Nil)
```

We have to write numbers in unary, which is not very fun. We can use type classes to convert `Nat` literals to their `SNat` singleton values.

#### Constructing `SNat` implicitly

```
class ISNat n where
  snat :: SNat n
```

As you might already expect, there are going to be two instances, for `0` and successors respectively. `0` is the obvious one:

```hs
instance ISNat 0 where
  snat = SZ
```

For successors, the term-level part is straightforward (`snat = SS snat`), but the types require a couple of tricks.

```hs
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (ISNat p, n ~ (1 + p)) => ISNat n where
  snat = SS snat
```

**First**, `OVERLAPPABLE`. There is no easy way to syntactically identify a type parameter `n` as "not `0`", so we use an `OVERLAPPABLE` instance. (There are other ways when overlap is unacceptable, but they are not as convenient.) When encountering an `ISNat n` constraint, the typechecker will always picks the most specific instance possible: if `n` is `0` it will pick the `0` instance, if `n` is a non-zero literal, it will pick this overlappable instance for successors because the `0` instance is not applicable, and if `n` is not equal to a literal (so it is an unconstrained type variable or some stuck type family application), the `0` instance might apply, we don't really know, so the typechecker will conservatively not pick either of these instances, and it will instead look in elsewhere its context for a suitable constraint, raising a compile-time error if none is found.

**Second**, `SS` wants its result type to be of the form `SNat (1 + p)`. So we add a constraint `n ~ (1 + p)`.

Note that to solve that constraint (when *using* `snat`), GHC will need to guess `p`, which the natnormalise plugin takes care of here; otherwise we could also have added a constraint `p ~ (n - 1)`.

With that we can finally write the example more conveniently using a `Nat` literal:

```
extend (snat :: SNat 3) "hi" ("foo" :@ "bar" :@ Nil)
```

The `snat :: SNat` bit might seem a little crufty. Taking care of that is left  as an exercise for the reader.

Full gist: https://gist.github.com/Lysxia/cf0f8ae509d36a11ddf58bfcea8abb89

Comment: This is very impressive, thank you very much for the instructive tutorial answer. I was able to remove the `snat :: Snat 3` part by defining a wrapping function which implies the `Nat` to the `SNat`: `extend' :: forall n m a . ISNat n => a -> LList m a -> LList (n + m) a` with the implementation `extend' = extend (snat @n)`. Thanks to `extend`, stuff like Monoid, Applicative can be implemented trivially: https://github.com/keksnicoh/thinking-with-types-notes/blob/master/src/LList.hs . One of my personal next chapters will be to getting used to the concept of Singletons :D